# braintreegateway Uncaught exception

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using [braintreegateway](https://www.braintreegateway.com) with the following code in `sandbox` mode.

Code is used from [developer site](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php)

```
require_once 'braintree/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('marchentid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('publickey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('privatekey');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
            'amount' => '100.00',
            'orderId' => '123',
            'merchantAccountId' => 'marchentid',
            'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonceFromTheClient',
            'customer' => [
                'firstName' => 'kapil',
                'lastName' => 'Smith',
                'company' => 'mycompany',
                'phone' => '1234567890',
                'website' => 'http://mywebsite.com',
                'email' => 'myemail'
            ],
            'billing' => [
                'firstName' => 'kapil',
                'lastName' => 'Smith',
                'company' => 'mycompany',
                'streetAddress' => 'address',
                'extendedAddress' => 'Suite 403',
                'locality' => 'India',
                'region' => 'IN',
                'postalCode' => 'zipcode',
                'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'IN'
            ],
            'shipping' => [
                'firstName' => 'kapil',
                'lastName' => 'Smith',
                'company' => 'mycompany',
                'streetAddress' => 'address',
                'extendedAddress' => 'Suite 403',
                'locality' => 'India',
                'region' => 'IN',
                'postalCode' => 'zipcode',
                'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'IN'
            ],
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => true
            ]
        ]);

if ($result->success) {
    print_r("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
    print_r("Error processing transaction:");
    print_r("\n  code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
    print_r("\n  text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText);
} else {
    print_r("Validation errors: \n");
    print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
}
```

and the result is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree\Exception\Authorization' in
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/Util.php:61 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/Http.php(47):
> Braintree\Util::throwStatusCodeException(403) #1
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(443):
> Braintree\Http->post('/merchants/dmmt...', Array) #2
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(49):
> Braintree\TransactionGateway->_doCreate('/transactions', Array) #3
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(268):
> Braintree\TransactionGateway->create(Array) #4
> /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/Transaction.php(494):
> Braintree\TransactionGateway->sale(Array) #5
> /var/www/html/api/payment.php(58): Braintree\Transaction::sale(Array)
>
> ## 6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/api/braintree/lib/Braintree/Util.php on line 61

what's wrong here?

Comment: Please provide the code which you tried! Here I can see only the values provided in the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Like @mfahadi mentioned, one potential problem may be that that your code doesn't have your keys in the `Braintree_Configuration` calls, but you should never post your keys to StackOverflow, even for sandbox accounts. So if it was intentionally filtered: well done. If not, check out the guide to [get your client keys](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials).

The second problem is you did not replace 'nonceFromTheClient' in the line below with an actual client nonce:

```
'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonceFromTheClient',
```

You can find a test nonce [in the testing reference guide.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php)

And replace the line above with the line below to fix your second problem:

```
'paymentMethodNonce' => 'fake-valid-nonce',
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already fix that issue. And you are right it is due to `nonceFromTheClient`. it take time to understand this. 
One thing I want to say if you are [at] Braintree that improve your document regarding `nonceFromTheClient` exploitation

Answer (score 3):

You are just trying to run a sample code, which has placeholders for info that you have to provide. You have to add that info for it to work.

```
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('marchentid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('publickey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('privatekey');
```

In above code you have to provie your merchentid, publikey and privatekey form Braintree conrol panel.

```
'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonceFromTheClient',
```

And then add the nounce from client. I would suggest reading up the docs for PHP server implementation and hosted fields to get a detailed understanding.

[Hosted Fileds Docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2)

[PHP Server Docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php)

*Not adding as comment because I don't have enough reputation.