# Braintree Sale Error (PHP)

Tags: php, payment, braintree, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a transaction with Braintree. In Sandbox it worked fine. My server is an AWS Beanstalk setup with a load balancer with SSL (TLS 1.2).

Here is the error from the error_log:

```
[Mon Mar 20 11:32:31.816499 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [client XX] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Braintree\\Exception\\Authorization in /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/Util.php:61\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/Http.php(47): Braintree\\Util::throwStatusCodeException(403)\n#1 /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(477): Braintree\\Http->post('/merchants/jtd9...', Array)\n#2 /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(49): Braintree\\TransactionGateway->_doCreate('/transactions', Array)\n#3 /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(289): Braintree\\TransactionGateway->create(Array)\n#4 /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/Transaction.php(502): Braintree\\TransactionGateway->sale(Array)\n#5 /var/app/current/ajax/add_points.php(23): Braintree\\Transaction::sale(Array)\n#6 {main}\n  thrown in /var/app/current/scripts/lib/Braintree/Util.php on line 61, referer: https://XX.com/dashboard
```

Here is the actual server-side PHP code:

```
require_once('../scripts/lib/Braintree.php');
Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xx');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xx');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xx');
$pym = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
$points = 10*1.5;

        $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
            'amount' => $points,
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'paymentMethodNonce' => $pym,
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => true
            ]
        ]);
```

The ::sale part of the code above is what gives me the error above. I tried doing an exit(); after including the Braintree.php file and all the configuration options, and it exits as expected, so the error is definitely caused by the ::sale part of the code.

All works fine in Sandbox, and nonce seems to be correctly generated client side, and then sent.

I'm not even sure where to start debugging. Any advice would help!

Comment: the thing with braintree is, when you put it in production mode, you need to follow all the things right from scratch which you did in sandbox (i.e. creating merchant account programatically etc) to proceed transaction.. are you following this ?

Comment: Yup - it looks like the authorisation is going through (the API keys are fine and working). When I hadn't set those keys up properly the error was clear to tell me that. Now, it looks like I'm facing a different issue :/

Comment: Yea .. check your merchant id .. which should be generated in your production mode and use it while you are doing transaction and all the stuff should be generated in production mode. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: The merchant ID is the same one provided at the API screen on Braintree. I just copy pasted the configuration options that braintree provides next to its API screen. From my end, it looks like the merchant ID and the API's are correct...

Comment: I see. IF you check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014461/braintreegateway-uncaught-exception

Comment: I've looked at that question. It looks like the person was not using the correct API keys. That is not the issue here... My real keys aren't "xx", thats just posted here so it's not shown publicly...

Comment: Full disclosure: I work for Braintree. Since you're receiving an error related to an Authorization Exception, as noted: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Util.php#L61, I would suggest reaching out to support: https://articles.braintreepayments.com/ so they can check your configuration, setup and server logs using your merchant id.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my clients application has been declined.

The key term here was **authorization** - which is different than **authentication** (which relates to API keys, that were correct).