# Braintree authorization error

Tags: php, authorization, braintree, production

I'm trying to setup the braintree method on a PHP web app and I have read most of given documentation on Braintree's website.

I ended up with a sandbox running perfectly so I decided switch it to production. I created a prod account and duplicated all the settings one by one. I then tried to make a payment on the production server and everytime I get the following error:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4OPu.png)

Did anyone encounter this issue? If so, did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked braintrees website for developers for this exception?

> Authorization Error
>   Braintree_Exception_Authorization
>
> Raised when the API key that you're using is not authorized to perform the attempted action according to the role assigned to the user who owns the API key.
>
> This error can also occur if the data you submitted was malformed – either a parameter isn't in the allowed list, or it is at the wrong location in the nested parameters.

[Authorization Exception on developers.braintreepayments.com](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/php#authorization-error)

Comment: Thank for trying to help me out.

Yes I checked that part of the documentation and I am sure that the role is not a problem because I am using a account with all privileges.

So maybe this can be coming from a malformation in the data sent.

You can take a look at my code here:
https://pastebin.com/xvym5G9B (form + js)
https://pastebin.com/RTsY8mY6 (sale request)

Comment: Have you searched SO for similar errors? Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014461/braintreegateway-uncaught-exception) Without a code to check, it's almost impossible to make a good assumption based on a vague exception name

Comment: Yes I did. I tried with the fake-valid nonce and I still get the same result.
I have checked the generated client nonce et it seems ok. Concerning the API merchantid and keys, I copy pasted them to the file so the problem is not coming from this either.
I edited my last comment, the pastebinsof my code were missing if you want to take a look.