# Fatal Error: Uncaught Braintree Exception in PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, braintree

I am using XAMPP latest version for mac and I am trying from this site https://www.appcoda.com/braintree-ios-integration/

PHP code is

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('**********');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('**********');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('************');

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$paymentMethodNonce =  $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];
echo $paymentMethodNonce;

$amount = $_POST['amount'];
echo $amount;

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
  'amount' => $amount,
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $paymentMethodNonce,
  'options' => [
    'submitForSettlement' => True
  ]
]);

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Why am I getting this error? I didn't understand from this site [braintreegateway Uncaught exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014461/braintreegateway-uncaught-exception)

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Braintree\Exception\SSLCertificate: Couldn't resolve host 'api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php:168 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php(99): Braintree\Http->_doUrlRequest('POST', 'https://api.san...', '_doRequest('POST', '/merchants/fxd6...', 'post('/merchants/fxd6...', Array) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(48): Braintree\TransactionGateway->_doCreate('/transactions', Array) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/TransactionGateway.php(290): Braintree\TransactionGateway->create(Array) #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dona in /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php on line 168

Comment: i hope you replaced those public and private keys with random values

Comment: Your code can't connect to the url "api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com". If I try to ping that URL, it does work. Also, please tell me those keys you posted aren't the actual keys of your project. If yes, change them right **now**.

Comment: @Loek I changed them anyway

Comment: @Scriptable Still, some bot may have scraped them already. Seen it happen so many times that I would still recommend OP to change his keys.

Comment: What will I do now?

Comment: Oh definitely, I just meant in the post obviously. @khan something is restricting your access to that address. try to ping it yourself or try a curl request

Comment: I tried via postman and through app but failed. Can you give answer?

Comment: its very difficult to tell you what is wrong, could be your development machine not connected to internet, firewall, hosts file entry, router, etc etc etc

Comment: try to post to https url instead of http. Also make sure you are passing correct currency symbol which was configured at your sandbox.

Comment: Where will I put HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that your server is not using TLSv1.2. As of December 13, 2016, we are no longer accepting connections using SSL (any version), TLSv1.0, or TLSv1.2 for the Sandbox environment. You can find more information about this change [in our blog post](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/updating-your-production-environment-to-support-tlsv1-2/). These changes will affect our Production environment soon as well.

To find the OpenSSL information for cURL, run:

`php -r 'echo json_encode(curl_version(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);'`

You can take a look at the [PayPal Guideline](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php) for updating your SSL/TSL libraries and information for updating the OpenSSL version on your machine as well.